# Can OpenSSL be bundled for wget wrapper app to reference in Xcode project?

Tags: swift, xcode, openssl, xcode8, wget

I wrote a wrapper app for wget since there is other pre-process that I want to do and use it to run wget.

My wget is installed by homebrew.  I used this wget binary in Xcode project and bundled it.

Now I realized it references openssl in
/usr/local/opt/bin ... 
in order to run.  Since I have it installed in there, I don't have problem.  However, for other environment that did not have openssl in that particular directory, wrapper app just crashes.

Is there way to include and bundle openssl in Xcode project and make wget to reference it within an app, so others don't need to go through separate installation of openssl in order to use this wrapper app?

Comment: I've seen this asked twice before in the context of OpenSSL, but I don't recall seeing a really good answer. Brew adds an additional twist. Also see [Building a Mac OS X/Cocoa application for distribution with an imported framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7074668/608639) and [“Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib” with Xcode 8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43150655/608639).

Comment: @jww Thanks for responding.  Yes, I saw similar questions and comments, too, but there weren't really solid solution.  I wonder if this is even possible.