# How to bundle and distribute Nginx to other OS X machines

Tags: macos, nginx, openssl, bundle

I have installed ngnix on mac from source using below commands.

```
cd pcre-8.40
/configure --prefix=/Users/nginx/
make && make install && make clean
cd ..
cd ngnix-1.10.3
/configure --prefix=/Users/nginx/ --with-pcre=../pcre-8.40 --with-http_ssl_module
make && make install && make clean
```

nginx works fine when i run it from the installed machine.

Now, I have copied nginx folder from /Users/nginx/ on another mac machine.

It is throwing the following error when I run sudo ./nginx.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: Users/nginx/sbin/./nginx
  Reason: no suitable image found.
```

Tried many ways but no luck. Any idea on how to achieve this.

Comment: [“Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib” with Xcode 8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43150655/608639), [Building a Mac OS X/Cocoa application for distribution with an imported framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7074668/608639), [Can OpenSSL be bundled for wget wrapper app to reference in Xcode project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44523746/608639), etc. Apple's [Distributing Your Application](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Porting/Conceptual/PortingUnix/distributing/distibuting.html) may help.